# vim-autoformat and scalafmt not working

Tags: scala, vim, vim-plugin, autoformat

I am using the https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat plugin with scalafmt, and have the following in my .vimrc:

```
" scalafmt settings
let g:formatdef_scalafmt = "'scalafmt --stdin'"
let g:formatters_scala = ['scalafmt']

noremap <localleader>f :Autoformat<CR>

let g:autoformat_autoindent = 0
let g:autoformat_retab = 0
let g:autoformat_remove_trailing_spaces = 0
```

I have verified that scalafmt is working when I call it from outside vim. There are no error messages displayed, but the buffer does not get updated.

Running `:CurrentFormatter` results in: `Selected formatter: scalafmt`

Is there something missing from my configuration?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: vim-autoformat is working in my setup with other external formatters (e.g. Java), so I'm not sure this is a plugin issue. scalafmt also seems to be setup correctly, as `cat Hello.scala | scalafmt --stdin` writes the formatted file to the console.

Comment: You can set `:set verbose=1` and check the messages about what is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

just to make the answer complete,

```
let g:formatdef_scalafmt = '"scalafmt --stdin 2>/dev/null"'
let g:formatters_scala = ['scalafmt']
```

as suggested in [Issues using vim-autoformat with scalafmt](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat/issues/184)